# Visualizing Bendixson’s criterion

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, visualization

I would like to graphically show Bendixson’s criterion.

> **The Bendixson Criterion:**
>
> If $f_1$ and $f_2$ are continuous in a region $R$ which is simply-connected
>   (i.e., without holes), and
>
> $$\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1}+\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_2}\ne0$$ at any point of $R$,
>
> then the system
>
> $$x_1' = f_1(x_1, x_2)$$
>
> $$x_2' =  f_2(x_1, x_2)$$
>
> has no closed trajectories inside $R$.

Basically you can use this theorem to proof that there is no limit cycle within a system:

$$x' = f(x,y) $$

($x$ being a state vector and $f(x,y)$ the dynamic equation vector)

I wanted to visualize graphically that, if we HAVE a limit cycle $\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1}+\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_2}$ will be  equal  to zero at some points.

Hence I draw a limit cycle (simple circle in the $x_1-x_2$ plane).
Since $x'=f(x_1,x_2) \rightarrow f(x_1,x_2)$ will be tangent to the circle at all points, if the circle is a limit cycle (the trajectory can not escape).

[image]

```
Clear[t, x, y, z, P];
x[t_] = -Sin[t];
y[t_] = Cos[t];

P[t_] = {x[t], y[t]};
V[t_] = {x'[t], y'[t]};
curveplot = 
  ParametricPlot[P[t], {t, 0, 2*Pi}, PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.01]];

ar = Table[{P[t], P[t] + V[t]}, {t, 0, 2*Pi, Pi/4}];
Show[curveplot, 
 Graphics[{Arrow[ar], Red, AbsolutePointSize@10, Point@ar[[All, 1]]}],
  PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"x1", "x2"}, Ticks -> None]
```

**But how could I visualize: $\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1}+\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_2}$** ??
Any suggestions ?

Based on a comment from  Rahul: $\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1}+\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_2}$ is simply the divergence.

Hence I do the follwing:

Angle with x1 and x2:

```
f1[x1_, x2_] = -Sin[ArcTan[x2/x1]];
f2[x1_, x2_] = Cos[ArcTan[x2/x1]];

a = StreamPlot[{f1[x1, x2], f2[x1, x2]}, {x1, -1, 1}, {x2, -1, 1}];

Show[curveplot, a, 
 Graphics[{Arrow[ar], Red, AbsolutePointSize@10, Point@ar[[All, 1]]}],
  PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"x1", "x2"}, Ticks -> None]
```

[image]

EDIT: 
Thanks to J.M, I changed the ArcTan function to:

```
-Sin[ArcTan[x1, x2]]
```

and

```
Cos[ArcTan[x1, x2]]
```

(putting a comma between x1 and x2, gives the angle for this coordinate)

the output no looks better:

[image]

Now the question is:...**what could you interpret ?
...and is there a better way to visualize the divergence ?**

Any help is highly appreciated ! :)

Comment: $\partial f_1/\partial x_1+\partial f_2/\partial x_2$ is nothing but the divergence of the vector field $f$. You could draw the vector field itself and allow the viewer to interpret how much it is spreading out or contracting.

Comment: @Rahul nice suggestion, how do I draw the divergence onto the same plot ?

Comment: @Rahul have a look at my question. Added your suggestion... but there is probably a mistake.

Comment: @C.E. Would you mind to explain a bit more, I am still confused ... sorry.

Comment: @C.E and do you think the result is correct as visualized ?

Comment: @Rahul what do you think of the plot ?

Comment: What happens if you use `-Sin[ArcTan[x1, x2]]` and `Cos[ArcTan[x1, x2]]` instead?

Comment: @J.M. Thanks a lot ! Looks much better now. Have a look at the question.

Comment: I don't know what to think of it. The contour is not a limit cycle of the vector field you've drawn, because the tangents don't align with the vector field. So I don't know what the plot is supposed to mean.

Comment: @Rahul that is strange indeed. Do you see why?

Comment: @Rahul spotted my mistake ! I put ArcTan(x2,x1) instead of ArcTan(x1,x2).

Comment: Maybe try a ContourPlot of the Divergence....

Comment: What if the trajectory of the limit cycle is not a circle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps just exploring the linear case is sufficient. $\{x'(t),y'(t)\}=\vec{F}(x,y)=\{a x + b y,  cx+dy\}$. Closed trajectories occurs when $ad-bc>0$ and $a+d=0=\nabla\cdot \vec{F}$:

```
f[a_, b_, c_, d_, x_, y_] := {{a, b}, {c, d}}.{x, y}
Manipulate[Column[{
   Grid[{{"a+d= ",
      a + d}, {"ad-bc= ",
      a d - b c}}],

   Show[
    StreamPlot[f[a, b, c, d, x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
     Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[{0, 0}], Green, 
       Point[{1, 1}]}, ImageSize -> 400],
    ParametricPlot[
      Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. 
        First@DSolve[{{x'[t], y'[t]} == 
            f[a, b, c, d, x[t], y[t]], {x[0], y[0]} == {1, 1}}, {x[t],
            y[t]}, t]], {t, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}] /. 
     Line[q__] :> Arrow[q]
    ]
   }, Alignment -> Center],
 {a, {-1/4, 1/4}}, {b, -1, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {c, -1, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {d, {-1/4, 1/4}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Looks great, but what would be your interpretation ? When circles are formed, a limit cycle exists ?

Comment: @totyped sorry for the delay in replying. I put this as a way of visually illustrating which also includes case where div F=0 and there are no closed trajectories as well as the contrapositive to the statement of the theorem. I am certain there will be better answers. The linear case is just the simplest case (I thought of), :)